# Spring Tool Suite proxy authentication

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

java 6.0.45

STS Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE

STS Build Id: 201310051614

Windows 7

I just downloaded the latest Spring Source Toolsuite, I'm behind a proxy so I'm trying to configure the proxy authentication under preferences. I hit apply & ok, try to access the internet via File -> New -> Spring Starter Project I get a 407 error.
When I go back to the proxy preferences the user/password is empty.

Does anybody know how to configure proxy settings? Somwehere in the .metadata directory somewhere maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kepler had same issue:

After I changed my password in secure storage under `preferences-> Security -> Secure Storage`,
It finally let me store my username and password.

I somehow believe it has to do with corporate security desktop integration.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah it was frustrating. On a slight tangent, you may run into this issue of not being able to get out to the Internet soon. If you are behind a proxy, you want to go to window -> properties, search for proxy and switch to "manual" update the HTTP and HTTPS and clear the SOCKS entries (no values).This should enable STS to get through the proxy immediately. Apparently, this issue has more to do with Eclipse in STS rather than STS itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure proxy settings in `Internet Options` in `Control Panel`. Just click on `Connections` tab and `LAN Settings` button. Check `Use a proxy server for your LAN (...)` box and provide proxy details. Then go to Spring Tool Suite window and click on `Window` >> `Preferences` >> `General` >> `Network Connections` and choose Native from the `Active Provider` drop down list.

Comment: Yes but our proxy needs authentication via username/password. Which I would like to store somewhere, but sts doesn't let me store it..

Comment: So choose "Manual" instead of "Native", click on Socket and press "Edit" button. You can provide there either the username and the password.